# Independence of sample mean of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$, with $x$ uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$

Tags: self-study

I have the following problem. I define two sample means

$$ \bar{\omega} = {1 \over N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} A_{i}\sin\theta_{i}$$
$$ \bar{\tau} = {1 \over N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} A_{i}\cos\theta_{i}$$

Where $\theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$ and $A$ has some unknown probability distribution function (independent of $\theta$). $\theta_{i}$ are independent random variables drawn from $U(0,2\pi)$ and $A_{i}$ are independent and drawn from the distribution of $A$. I want to use the central limit theorem to argue that $\bar{\omega}$ and $\bar{\tau}$ are asymptotically normally distributed, and so the quantity

$$ I = \sqrt{\bar{\omega}^{2} + \bar{\tau}^{2}}$$

Is asymptotically Rayleigh distributed. However, one of the conditions for $I$ being Rayleigh distributed is that $\bar{\omega}$ and $\bar{\tau}$ are independent. I know that $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are uncorrelated but dependent variables, but I feel intuitively that the sample means given above should be asymptotically independent as $N \to \infty$, as the probability of randomly drawing the dependent $\sin\theta_{i}$ and $\cos\theta_{i}$ quantities from the two samples goes to zero. But this is just handwaving.

My question is whether the two sample means given above can be considered as asymptotically ($N \to \infty$) independent random variables, and how to show this if so. I am not looking for a detailed proof, just some ideas on how to proceed. Any information would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do the $\theta_i$ have the same distribution as $\theta$? Are the $\theta_i$'s _independent_ random variables? Are the $A_i$'s independent among themselves in addition to being independent of the $\theta_i$'s? ? Identically distributed, too? Can we assume that $E[A_i]=0$ or is the distribution completely unknown? Note that for the simple case $N=1, E[A]\neq 0$, the distribution of $I$ is Rician, not Rayleigh, People over on dsp.SE know a lot about this kind of stuff; you could try asking there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I added some information to the question. $\theta_{i}$ are independent variables drawn from $\theta$ probability distribution. Each $A_{i}$ is drawn independently from the distribution of $A$. I will take a look at the Rician distribution, thanks. Although $E[A] \neq 0$, I expect that $E[z] = 0$, where $z = A \sin\theta$. My naive expectation is that the sample means defined above will be asymptotically normally distributed, but would like to understand if they are also asymptotically independent (also my naive expectation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $A$ has finite variance, the multivariate Central Limit Theorem says that $(\omega,\tau)$, suitably scaled, are asymptotically bivariate Normal.  Since they are uncorrelated, and uncorrelated bivariate Normals are independent, they are asymptotically independent.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for your answer. Is the multivariate Central Limit Theorem applicable if $(\omega, \tau)$ are dependent variables?

Comment: Yes. It wouldn't be much use otherwise.  The things that have to be independent are $A_i$, $A_j$ when $i\neq j$, and $\theta_i$, $\theta_j$ when $i\neq j$